# Customize Bar Chart using Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a question regarding bar chart color customization. I have a Grouped Bar Chart like the one below.

**I want to know how it is possible to customize only the first column of each occurrence.**

[image]

Part of the code I created to build this chart is below:

```
# Create the chart
colors = ['royalblue'] * len(df5)

for i in range(0,len(df5),1):

if df5['wip_higher'][i] == 0:
    colors[df5.index[i]] = 'palegreen'
    
elif df5['wip_higher'][i] == 1:
    colors[df5.index[i]] = 'moccasin'
    
elif df5['wip_higher'][i] == 2:
    colors[df5.index[i]] = 'goldenrod'
    
elif df5['wip_higher'][i] == 3:
    colors[df5.index[i]] = 'salmon'

elif df5['wip_higher'][i] == 4:
    colors[df5.index[i]] = 'black'


fig = px.bar(df5,
            x='Issue key',
            y=['time_wip', 'planned_effort'],
            template='plotly_white',
            text_auto=True,
            barmode='group',
            width=1000,
            labels={'y': 'Time in WIP (in Days)',
                'x': 'Issue Key'}
            )

fig.update_layout(legend=dict(orientation="h",
                            yanchor="bottom",
                            y=1.02,
                            xanchor="right",
                            x=1),
                legend_title_text='')

fig.update_traces(marker_color=colors)

fig.show()
```

I have tried different approaches, but none worked.

I appreciate your help.

Regards,
Marcelo

Comment: You will have to create two subplots on the y axis, one envolving the first bar and the other envolving the second bar. After that just play a little bit with the colour parameter and parabin parabum

Comment: Not sure, but I feel this may give an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72814480/plot-bar-graph-with-different-parametes-in-x-axis

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973404/setting-different-bar-color-in-matplotlib-python) help to you

Answer (score 1):

How about creating them as seperate traces and style each individually?

```
fig = px.Bar()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Issue Key'], y=df['time_wip']...style as needed)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Issue Key'], y=df['planned_effort']... style as needed)
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for all the answers, I found in the documentation (which is not very well organized) this option. I tried and I could solve it without changing the rest of my code.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).